# Как вызвать активити чтобы предыдущие уничтожились

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity, android-intent

Как мне вызвать Активити2 путем нажатия кнопки в Активити1, так чтобы Активити2 стала единственной (т.е. когда жмешь кнопку "назад" то приложение закрывалось)
(ну вызов активити2 я уже реализовал всё есть, я только не знаю как сделать её единственной активити приложения)

Comment: попробуйте finishAffinity()

Answer (score 0):

Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android start activity clear stack](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20start%20activity%20clear%20stack)

и вот этому ответу с [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344635/3212712)

вам надо добавить флаги к интенту так:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такой код:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent2);
finish();
```

Comment: ```finish()``` закроет только ту активити, где он был вызван. Этот способ не подойдет если у вас в стеке больше 2х активити и надо убить все.

Comment: Но в данном случае это панацея(хотя и немного костыльная) так как в приложении всего 2 активити.

Comment: В дальнейшем эти две активити с легкостью преобразуются в 3, 5, а то и все 10, и если есть кейс в котором надо закрыть все и запустить одну, то лучше сделать сразу правильно и не возвращаться к этому вопросу и не ловить баги.

Comment: Согласен с вами, но я предложил временное решение для данной проблемы